# Component that hold controls in a tabular style?

Tags: delphi

I'm looking for a component that can hold another components (Like buttons) and show them in a tabular style. `GridPanel` is a such a component but does not show those grids runtime.

Something like this:

[image: sample]

Comment: You can include a image to your question to show what look are you looking for, and try to explain better. For example, what's not clear to me is if you want the component to "repeat" the contained components or not. Also the "tabular style" is not clear to me, but that's maybe because I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Excuse me for my bad English. I'm just want a component like `ListView` but each cell can holds another component like `GridPanel`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use TGridpanel and implement your own logic for painting by overriding the Paint method.
The appended image shows what it would look like, to reach your expected result, some code needs to be added.[image]

```
unit Unit6;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type

  TGridPanel = Class(ExtCtrls.TGridPanel)
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  end;

  TCellItem = Class(ExtCtrls.TCellItem)
    Property Size;  // make protected Size accessable
  End;

  TForm6 = class(TForm)
    GridPanel1: TGridPanel;
    Button6: TButton;
    Button7: TButton;
    Button8: TButton;
    Button10: TButton;
    Button11: TButton;
    Button12: TButton;
    Button14: TButton;
    Button15: TButton;
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form6: TForm6;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses TypInfo, Rtti;

Function GetSize(B: TComponent): Integer;
var
  c: TRttiContext;
  t: TRttiInstanceType;
begin
  c := TRttiContext.Create;
  try
    t := c.GetType(B.ClassInfo) as TRttiInstanceType;
    Result := t.GetProperty('Width').GetValue(B).AsInteger;
  finally
    c.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TGridPanel.Paint;
var
  I: Integer;
  LinePos, Size: Integer;
  ClientRect: TRect;
begin
  inherited;
  begin
    LinePos := 0;
    Canvas.Pen.Style := psSolid;
    Canvas.Pen.Color := clBlack;
    ClientRect := GetClientRect;
    Canvas.Rectangle(ClientRect);
    for I := 0 to ColumnCollection.Count - 2 do
    begin     // cast to "own" TCellItem to access size
      Size := TCellItem(ColumnCollection[I]).Size;

      if I = 0 then
        Canvas.MoveTo(LinePos + Size, ClientRect.Top)
      else   // "keep cells together"
        Canvas.MoveTo(LinePos + Size, ClientRect.Top + TCellItem(RowCollection[0]).Size);

      Canvas.LineTo(LinePos + Size, ClientRect.Bottom);
      Inc(LinePos, Size);
    end;

    Canvas.Font.Size := 12;
    Canvas.TextOut(TCellItem(ColumnCollection[0]).Size + 20,
      (TCellItem(RowCollection[0]).Size - Canvas.TextHeight('X')) div 2,
      'a longer caption text to be displayed');

    LinePos := 0;
    for I := 0 to RowCollection.Count - 2 do
    begin
      Size := TCellItem(RowCollection[I]).Size;
      Canvas.MoveTo(ClientRect.Left, LinePos + Size);
      Canvas.LineTo(ClientRect.Right, LinePos + Size);
      Inc(LinePos, Size);
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```